# Is it fine to create a custom exception class that has the same name as a built in one in apex?

Tags: apex, exception

I need to throw exceptions within my apex classes here and there, as most of us do. In fact, we can't throw built-in exceptions so we have to create a custom one that extends from the main exception class. I face a situation most often where there is a built-in exception that completely matches my situation, let's say the `InvalidParameterValueException` when an empty string is passed as a param to a method. I have created a custom exception with the exact same name and am able to use it with no problem. 
**My question is: Is there a problem to do this?**
*and I know that I can just simply change the exception name slightly to differentiate the built-in one from my custom one, but this question is just for clarification on what are potential issues that can occur and the risk involved.* Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can*, except that if you do so, if any other code anywhere in your code base references that exception, you may get unexpected results. For example, consider:

```
public class DmlException extends Exception {
    /* Implementation here */
}
```

And somewhere else in your code base:

```
try {
    insert records;
} catch(DmlException e) {
    /* handle the error */
}
```

You'll be surprised to find that this exception **will not** be caught. You've just shadowed the default exception with a custom one, and now none of those try-catch blocks will work.

Every time you use that try-catch, you'll get:

> Uncaught System.DmlException: ... blah blah blah ...

You'd have to scour your entire code base, and replace all of them:

```
try {
    insert records;
} catch(System.DmlException e) {
    /* handle the error */
}
```

Also, you'll be inviting anyone else who ever works on your code, ever, to fall in to the same trap (including your future self a year from now that forgot that you did this).

So, while you technically *can*, I strongly advise that you do not, as it can, and probably will, break completely unrelated code in hilarious but infuriatingly difficult-to-fix and/or difficult-to-debug ways.

Finally, there are other subtle nuances, such as the fact that you may break unmanaged or unlocked packages that do not expect you do override a default exception class (managed packages would be safe from this problem, however).

Answer (score 1):

sfdcfox is quite correct in his answer that you can but shouldn't create your own exception with the same name.

It's worth pointing out that in the example you gave, `InvalidParameterValueException`, you can can construct and throw the system exception e.g.

```
@IsTest
private class ThrowSystemExceptionTest {

    public class ThrowSystemEx {
        public ThrowSystemEx() {
            InvalidParameterValueException e = new InvalidParameterValueException('a', 'b');
            e.setMessage('Expected better parameters');
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @IsTest
    static void uncaught() {
        new ThrowSystemEx();
    }
    @IsTest
    static void caught() {
        try {
            new ThrowSystemEx();
        } catch(InvalidParameterValueException e) {
            System.debug('Caught with message: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The `uncaught()` example fails the test, but with the sort of stack trace you'd hope for with a normal exception.

The `caught()` example shows that you can catch and handle the exception as normal.

Throwing the system exception probably solves your underlying problem with the minimum of ugliness.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! would you please explain on how comes it’s possible to construct the InvalidParameterValueException in the class constructor?